# Is there a way to know if a filename is an Excel format?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vb.net

My question may seem quite trivial but despite my numerous research, i haven't found an answer.

**Is there a way in .NET to know if a filename is an Excel spreadsheet ?**

I am not interested in the specific extension (.xls, .xlsx, etc), i would just like to know if the file is an excel generic spreadsheet.

Comment: you need to look for the Magic Number™ :)

Comment: Could you tell me more about it ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you would like to do this rather then to just create a list with all the known file extensions for Excel spreadsheets and see if the files extension is in that list?

Comment: you can use Epplus Library.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)

Comment: @karl-henrik Yes, because the file extension could have been changed by the user...

Comment: @karl-henrik Basicly it is all the file formats present in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat in the Microsoft Interop Object Librairy, which represents around 60 different extensions.

Comment: @GuidoPreite From what i understand, there is only magic numbers for Microsoft format, which includes Words, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long ago, I wrote something similar here is the code:

```
private enum Extensions
{
    Unknown = 0,
    DocOrXls,
    Pdf,
    Jpg,
    Png,
    DocxOrXlsx,
}

private static readonly Dictionary<Extensions, string> ExtensionSignature = new Dictionary<Extensions, string>
    {
        {Extensions.DocOrXls, "D0-CF-11-E0-A1-B1-1A-E1"},
        {Extensions.Pdf, "25-50-44-46"},
        {Extensions.Jpg, "FF-D8-FF-E"},
        {Extensions.Png, "89-50-4E-47-0D-0A-1A-0A"},
        {Extensions.DocxOrXlsx, "50-4B-03-04-14-00-06-00"}
    };

private static string GetExtension(byte[] bytes)
{
    if (bytes.Length < 8)
        return string.Empty;
    var signatureBytes = new byte[8];
    Array.Copy(bytes, signatureBytes, signatureBytes.Length);
    string signature = BitConverter.ToString(signatureBytes);
    Extensions extension = ExtensionSignature.FirstOrDefault(pair => signature.Contains(pair.Value)).Key;
    switch (extension)
    {
        case Extensions.Unknown:
            return string.Empty;
        case Extensions.DocOrXls:
            if (bytes.Length < 512)
                break;
            signatureBytes = new byte[4];
            Array.Copy(bytes, 512, signatureBytes, 0, signatureBytes.Length);
            signature = BitConverter.ToString(signatureBytes);
            if (signature == "EC-A5-C1-00")
                return ".doc";
            return ".xls";
        case Extensions.Pdf:
            return ".pdf";
        case Extensions.Jpg:
            return ".jpg";
        case Extensions.Png:
            return ".png";
        case Extensions.DocxOrXlsx:
            string fileBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            if (fileBody.Contains("word"))
                return ".docx";
            if (fileBody.Contains("xl"))
                return ".xlsx";
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to read the file Header bytes in order to know exactly what kind of file it is.

This library here [FileTypeDetective](http://filetypedetective.codeplex.com/) does exactly what you want, but looks like the project is no longer active. Anyway it and can be easily adapted/corrected once you get the idea.

See:

```
// MS Office files
        public readonly static FileType WORD = new FileType(new byte?[] { 0xEC, 0xA5, 0xC1, 0x00 }, 512, "doc", "application/msword");
        public readonly static FileType EXCEL = new FileType(new byte?[] { 0x09, 0x08, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x05, 0x00 }, 512, "xls", "application/excel");
        public readonly static FileType PPT = new FileType(new byte?[] {0xFD, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, null, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00  }, 512, "ppt", "application/mspowerpoint");
```

All you have to do is to find a common signature among all excel files.

My guess is that this library still works very well. I see no reason for these headers have changed since 2012 (last release).

Comment: That sounds more elegant than the workaround i've been trying, i'm going to dig on this, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You could create a `try-catch` statement and see if Excel can open the file:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

....

try
{
    Application app = new Application();
    Workbook book = app.Workbooks.Open(@workbookPath); //@workbookpath is the file path
}
catch
{
    //Excel encountered an error opening the file at the path
}
```

Comment: That would be a good idea, but excel could open a .txt file, am i right ?

Comment: @PierreRoudaut That is true, but it would add the lines into different rows, which technically could mean that it can work as an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Technically it is. I like your solution but the only problem is that the filenames i get are from an outlook message. If i'd want to open it with excel, i'd have to save it physically on the filesystem somewhere, which is one of the things i'd like to avoid by filtering on the extensions first if you see what i mean.

Comment: @PierreRoudaut If that's the case, I think you can script Outlook (using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`) to process the message and grab the attachment. You could then cache the file somewhere, check if Excel can read it, and delete it afterwards. It's not the best solution, but it's a potential workaround.

Comment: I would not recommend this technique. Avoid the use of exception just to validate things. Your code may catch it, but is still an exception.

Comment: @miguelarcilla This is what i am already using to parse the attachments in the emails but i wanted to avoid saving the file (which can take quite some time). I think i'm finally going to list all the extensions i'll allow and compare the end of the filename, Thanks for your help anyway !